Узнать количество подписчиков группы ВК без авторизации
Нужно узнать количество подписчиков группы ВК
с авторизацией понятно как сделать через апи метод groups.getById
а без авторизации? прямой GET запрос https://vk.com/mygroup не возвращает никакой инфы по группе. Может есть какой то лайфхак/костыль?

Если же одна или заведомо известный список групп, то просто спарсить

@MaxDown спарсить я могу, но откуда? прямая ссылка https://vk.com/mygroup без авторизации инфы никакой не дает

Попробуйте selenium

@babyborn В предыдущем ответе как раз и говорится, что если заведомо известна группа или несколько групп. То есть прямые ссылки на группу
Если же требуются группы пользователя и информация о них. То в таком случае надеется, что у пользователя открыта страница и парсить с неё
